# show it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i)$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials

How can I show that
$x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ and $x^2-\sqrt{2} ix-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}\left( i\right)$?

I think showing it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)$ is the same as showing irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$, is it right?

Can I find the root for the polynomial by USING $\frac {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}} {2a}$ and see if it is belong to $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ or $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ or none of the above?

please any hint with that

Comment: Do they have roots over any of the respective field?

Comment: yes , they have

Comment: Which roots did you find for these polynomials?

Comment: can I find the root for the polynomial by USING (b±√ (b^2-4ac))/2a and see if it is belong to R , Q(i) , and Q(√ 2) or not?

Comment: This formula is valid in any field, provided $b^2-4ac$ has a square root. B.t.w. don't use the surd notation here: it denotes the positive (real) square root of a positive number.

Comment: so how can I show it for  Q(i) , and Q(√ 2) please

Comment: @rianasd I think you're almost there. Do you remember how to determine a quadratic equation over R having two distinct real roots, one repeated real root or no real roots?

Comment: @rianasd Also, I want to add that it does not make sense to ask if $x^2 - \sqrt{2} x + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ since the coefficient $-\sqrt{2}$ is not even in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$. It only makes sense to ask if $x^2 - \sqrt{2} x + 1$ is irreducible in field containing $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ as subfield, for examples $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: b^2 - 4ac > 0 has 2 different real roots .b^2 - 4ac = 0 has 2 equal real roots , and b^2 - 4ac < 0 has 2 complex roots

Comment: Yes, so what do you get if you plug in the formula?

Comment: you mean I have to use b^2 - 4ac < 0 has 2 complex roots to show it is irreducible over Q(i) ?

Comment: @rianasd No, I mean you can use $b^2 - 4ac < 0$ to show $x^2 - \sqrt{2}x + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$. Hence also irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ since it is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$,

Answer (score 0):

Solve the respective quadratic equations over $\;R\;$ . For the first one we get:

$$\Delta_1=2-4=-2$$

so it has no roots in $\;\Bbb R\;$ and thus **also** not in $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)\subset\Bbb R\;$ . Add the little details left.

For the second one we have, over $\;\Bbb C\;$ :

$$\Delta_2=-2+4=2\implies x_{1,2}=\frac{\sqrt2\,i\pm\sqrt2}2=\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac1{\sqrt2}i=\frac1{\sqrt2}(\pm1+i)$$

so if $\;x^2-\sqrt2\,ix-1=\left(x-\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac1{\sqrt2}i\right)\right)\left(x+\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac1{\sqrt2}i\right)\right)\;$ reducible over $\;\Bbb Q(i)\;$ , then

$$\frac1{\sqrt2}\in\Bbb Q(i)\implies \sqrt2\in\Bbb Q(i)$$

which is absurd as then we can write

$$\sqrt2=a+bi\;,\;\;a,b\in\Bbb Q\implies a=\sqrt2\,,\,\,b=0$$

by comparing real and imaginary *real* parts ...